# error creating buffer to load data

Tags: c++, allegro5

I have a problem with loading data from file.
This piece of code fills high scores with some random data (its just for debug)

```
int i = 0; 
for (i = 0; i < MAX_HIGH_SCORE; i++)
{
    high_score_name[i] = al_ustr_new("123456789012345678901");
    high_score[i] = 1000*i;
}
```

after that i save all of that to file.

```
ALLEGRO_FILE* high_score_file = al_fopen("hs.txt","wb");
for (i = 0; i < MAX_HIGH_SCORE; i++)
{
    int buffer = al_ustr_size(high_score_name[i]);
    al_fwrite32le(high_score_file, buffer);
    al_fwrite(high_score_file, al_cstr(high_score_name[i]), buffer);
    al_fwrite(high_score_file, &high_score[i], sizeof(high_score[i]));

}
al_fclose(high_score_file);
```

It work just fine. It have four bytes reserved for size then 21 characters of `high_score_name[]` followed by `high_score[]` int which takes also 4 bytes.

Problem starts when i try to load it up. I tried to do in many ways but it won`t compile because line

`char* buffer= al_malloc(size);` 
gives error :

> a value of type "void *" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "char *

```
for (i = 0; i < MAX_HIGH_SCORE; i++)
{
    int size = al_fread32le(high_score_file);
    char* buffer = al_malloc(size);
    al_fread(high_score_file, buffer, size);
    high_score_name[i] = al_ustr_new_from_buffer(buffer, size);

    int *buffer2 = &high_score[i];          
    al_fread(high_score_file, buffer2, sizeof(high_score[i]));

    al_free(buffer);
}

al_fclose(high_score_file);
```

Im stuck with it for two days and i would really apreciate any help.

Comment: Try to add a cast before calling `al_malloc( )` i.e. `char *buffer = (char *) al_malloc(size);`.

Comment: it helped with the error but now i`m getting 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xFEEEFEF6 when size is initialized.

Comment: `0xFEEEFEEE : Used by Microsoft's HeapFree() to mark freed heap memory` http://stackoverflow.com/a/127404/487892

Comment: on failure al_fread32le( ) returns -1.  You need an if-statement before the al_malloc( ) call to make sure size > 0.

Comment: i added `if(size>0)` statement after using `al_fread32le();` but im getting Access violation when program executes `int size = al_fread32le(high_score_file);` Value of size is `-858993460` and in a file its 15 00 00 00 (which is 21 in decimal)

Comment: @bfg9000 Is that the same access violation that you posted above that said you were using a pointer to memory on the heap that was already deallocated?

Comment: @drescherjm `First-chance exception at 0x6829A31A (allegro-5.0.10-monolith-mt-debug.dll) in Bricks.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xFEEEFEF6.` thats the full error and im getting when initializing`int size`

Comment: ok code works fine now. Turns out i wasnt opening the file again.

Comment: You need to figure out why high_score_file was deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output of malloc has type void* which you should try explicitly casting to char* .

```
char* buffer = static_cast<char *>(al_malloc(size))
```

Answer (score 0):

If your function internally uses malloc to allocate memory, then malloc returns a void* and if your al_malloc returns void*...Use type cast to conert it to char*.

char* buffer = (char*)al_malloc(size);

This should work.

Function prototype of malloc:

```
  void *malloc(size_t size);
```